# Changing the key in SQLCipher Android

Tags: java, android, sqlcipher

How do you programatically change the key for an SQLCipher database in Android?

Answer (score 2):

You can rekey a database by executing a `PRAGMA rekey` command.  More information can be found [here](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/#rekey).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this URL

https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/

Android now officially port of SQLCipher core project! More at: http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/

Source code and binaries: https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher